# How to append the body of an environment to an output file?

Tags: environments, auxiliary-files, body

I want to define an environment that expands as its body, which can contain mostly arbitrary content, and also appends its body (with some predictable level of expansion) to a file. (Motivation at the end.)

### M(non)WE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newwrite\Mine
\immediate\openout\Mine=\jobname.mine

\NewEnviron{MyEnv}{
  \immediate\write\Mine{\BODY}
  \BODY
}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnv}
Some Stuff that \emph{might} have \textbf{some} markup
and newlines\footnotes{And maybe other things.}.
\end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

This fails at the `\immediate\write\Mine{\BODY}` which seems to break internal details of everything after it.

---

- In my case the body content is something that makes a reasonable list item and will be *mostly* verbiage (things you could easily read aloud), but I'd like to get the least restricted solution I can.
- I don't care *much* about the level of expansion before the results hit the file. I'm expecting to do some post processing outside LaTeX and that needs to generate *more or less* the same text as a copy/pasting to a text file from what the environment expands to in a PDF. (E.g. I can tolerate the `\footnote{...}` showing up expanded or as a number, but I'd rather not have it's body show up inline without markup. I'd kind of like `\nameref{...}` to work, but I could live without it, particularly if finding them in the output isn't hard.)

I've found a few plausible solutions that don't work for a verity of reasons. (E.g. `VerbatimOut` doesn't work inside an environment definition and also doesn't support append.) Searches for solutions finds thing for the bits of this, but I have yet to find pieces that all fit together and work.

---

### Motivation:

I actually need to output both the verbiage of the body and some collected context that is going to be fed into some analysts to check that it satisfies some complex not-relevant-to-this-question criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\meaning`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newwrite\Mine
\immediate\openout\Mine=\jobname.mine

\NewEnviron{MyEnv}{
  \immediate\write\Mine{\meaning\BODY} %Changed for answer
  \BODY
}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnv}
Some Stuff that \emph{might} have \textbf{some} markup
and newlines\footnote{And maybe other things.}. %Changed for answer (assuming \footnotes was a typo)
\end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works. It adds a little markup I'll need to strip, but I was kind of expecting that even if I was hoping otherwise.

Comment: @BCS --- There might be a better way, but I suspect that post-processing will be easier than trying to get ideal output from TeX.

Comment: Given the post processing is intended to eventually include ML...  I've been know to use the wrong tool to do crazy things, but even *I'm* not **that** stupid. :0)